# RxJava zip operation on a varying length of Retrofit Observable array

Tags: rx-java, observable, retrofit2, rx-android

I have a varying length of Observable array. I would like to zip the requests (i.e. make a bunch of API requests and wait until all of them finish), but I cannot figure out how to implement the zip function.

```
Observable.zip(observables, new FuncN<List<ResponseBody>>() {
    @Override
    public List<ResponseBody> call(Object... args) {
        return Arrays.asList(args); <- compile error here
    }
});
```

Here the `obserables` is an array of `List<Observable<ResponseBody>>` and its length is unknown apriori.

The parameter of call in zip function cannot be corrected to `ResponseBody...`. How to make it return `Observable<List<ResponseBody>>`?

Is it a constraint in the design of `FuncN` RxJava 1.x.x?

P.S. I am using **RxJava 1.1.6**.

Comment: what is the problem exactly? the returned Type of FuncN method is the type of items that will be emitted by the created operator using the zip method, meaning here you'll have Observable<List<ResponseBody>>

Comment: @yosriz, the problem is `Arrays.asList(args)` is not of `List<ResponseBody>` type, and it leads to compilation error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just [merge](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html) your observables and collect results using `toList`:

```
Observable.merge(observables).toList()
```

Comment: May I know if `merge` operation would block each request? I wish to fire the requests async at the same time, so that the requests will not block each other.

Comment: `merge` won't block, but `Observable.concat` will

Comment: I just have a try, I found the requests are being sent one by one, i.e. only the first request's had response before the 2nd request is being fired...

Comment: Did you mean you get this order: `1st request, 1st response, 2nd request, 2nd response, 3rd request, 3rd response`...?

Comment: Yes, I get this order when I use merge.

Comment: It's expected when there is no delay between subscription and result delivery. A result delivers faster than next Observable starts. But if you'll test with a delay on each Observable everything will fall into place.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm `merge` operator works and find the culprit which causes the order: `1st request, 1st response, 2nd request, 2nd response, 3rd request, 3rd response`.

The observable in `observables` list is not subscribed on `Scheduler.io()` during adding.

Previously:

```
observables.add(mViewModelDelegate.get().getApiService()
                    .rxGetCategoryBrandList(baseUrl, categoryId));
```

After:

```
observables.add(mViewModelDelegate.get().getApiService()
                    .rxGetCategoryBrandList(baseUrl, categoryId)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

Answer (score 0):

User merge and make sure all observable requests have their own thread.
You can try this:

```
private void runMyTest() {
    List<Single<String>> singleObservableList = new ArrayList<>();
    singleObservableList.add(getSingleObservable(500, "AAA"));
    singleObservableList.add(getSingleObservable(300, "BBB"));
    singleObservableList.add(getSingleObservable(100, "CCC"));
    Single.merge(singleObservableList)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
}

private Single<String> getSingleObservable(long waitMilliSeconds, String name) {
    return Single
            .create((SingleOnSubscribe<String>) e -> {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(waitMilliSeconds);
                    } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("name = " +name+ ", waitMilliSeconds = " +waitMilliSeconds+ ", thread name = " +Thread.currentThread().getName()+ ", id =" +Thread.currentThread().getId());
                    if(!e.isDisposed()) e.onSuccess(name);
                })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}
```

Output:

> System.out: name = CCC, waitMilliSeconds = 100, thread name =
>   RxCachedThreadScheduler-4, id =463
>
> System.out: CCC
>
> System.out: name = BBB, waitMilliSeconds = 300, thread name =
>   RxCachedThreadScheduler-3, id =462
>
> System.out: BBB
>
> System.out: name = AAA, waitMilliSeconds = 500, thread name =
>   RxCachedThreadScheduler-2, id =461
>
> System.out: AAA